# XML-23006: (Error) value does not match required type on upgrade to XSL 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have recently changed my XSL to version 2.0 from version 1.0 to add some changes. I needed to add the SUM function for the following line:

```
<xsl:sequence select="sum (/ns0:PublishZXQPPWORKORDER/ns0:ZXQPPWORKORDERSet/ns0:WORKORDER/ns0:WOACTIVITY/(ns0:ESTLABCOST + ns0:ESTMATCOST))"/>
```

This caused me to get the error:
XML-23006: (Error) value does not match required type

On the following line:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/ns0:PublishZXQPPWORKORDER/ns0:ZXQPPWORKORDERSet/ns0:WORKORDER/ns0:PLUSDESTCONTROL/ns0:PLUSDESTVERSION[ns0:ESTVERSION=$VERSION]/ns0:PLUSDACGDETAIL/ns0:LBRCOSTOUT + /ns0:PublishZXQPPWORKORDER/ns0:ZXQPPWORKORDERSet/ns0:WORKORDER/ns0:PLUSDESTCONTROL/ns0:PLUSDESTVERSION[ns0:ESTVERSION=$VERSION]/ns0:PLUSDACGDETAIL/ns0:SERVICECOST + /ns0:PublishZXQPPWORKORDER/ns0:ZXQPPWORKORDERSet/ns0:WORKORDER/ns0:PLUSDESTCONTROL/ns0:PLUSDESTVERSION[ns0:ESTVERSION=$VERSION]/ns0:PLUSDACGDETAIL/ns0:MATLCOSTIN + /ns0:PublishZXQPPWORKORDER/ns0:ZXQPPWORKORDERSet/ns0:WORKORDER/ns0:PLUSDESTCONTROL/ns0:PLUSDESTVERSION[ns0:ESTVERSION=$VERSION]/ns0:PLUSDACGDETAIL/ns0:MATLCOSTOUT + /ns0:PublishZXQPPWORKORDER/ns0:ZXQPPWORKORDERSet/ns0:WORKORDER/ns0:PLUSDESTCONTROL/ns0:PLUSDESTVERSION[ns0:ESTVERSION=$VERSION]/ns0:PLUSDACGDETAIL/ns0:TOOLCOSTIN + /ns0:PublishZXQPPWORKORDER/ns0:ZXQPPWORKORDERSet/ns0:WORKORDER/ns0:PLUSDESTCONTROL/ns0:PLUSDESTVERSION[ns0:ESTVERSION=$VERSION]/ns0:PLUSDACGDETAIL/ns0:TOOLCOSTOUT"/>
```

The sample data I am using is the following:

```
<LBRCOSTOUT>0.0</LBRCOSTOUT>
<SERVICECOST>0.0</SERVICECOST>
<MATLCOSTIN>260.36</MATLCOSTIN>
<MATLCOSTOUT>0.0</MATLCOSTOUT>
<TOOLCOSTIN>0.0</TOOLCOSTIN>
<TOOLCOSTOUT>0.0</TOOLCOSTOUT>
```

Is this because of the stronger typing in XSL 2.0? What ways can I fix this?

Comment: When I google the mentioned error message it seems to be related to Oracle's XSLT processor. Have you tried to run your code with Saxon 9 for comparison? As for your code snippets, how does the first snippet relate to the second, is the value computed in the first snippet used in the second? It might help us if you try to reduce the code to minimal but complete snippets allowing us to easily reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The XPath that you passed to `sum()` is invalid:

```
/ns0:PublishZXQPPWORKORDER/ns0:ZXQPPWORKORDERSet
    /ns0:WORKORDER/ns0:WOACTIVITY/(ns0:ESTLABCOST + ns0:ESTMATCOST))
                                  ^
```

The noted `(` does not belong there.

I'm also not sure why you're creating a sequence from the output of `sum()` or how you're using this later in your code, but your change is syntactically wrong if nothing else.